# Android - setChoiceMode on custom ListView = no effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am using custom adapter which I use for my **ListView**. After creating ArrayList

```
WifiListAdapter<WifiListItem> adapter = new WifiListAdapter<WifiListItem>(
            this, R.layout.listview_item_text, listItems);
```

I have the following code in my app:

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, when I try to click on the checkbox, nothing happens. So I have to manage toggling checkbox state  manually.

```
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    CheckedTextView checkBox = (CheckedTextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.text1);
    if (checkBox != null) {
        checkBox.toggle();
```

Then it works. ( before that I have to remove setChoiceMode method call )

So what could be the problem? Why there is no effect?

my R.layout.listview_item_text.xml

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/topText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/botText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorTertiary"
 />
```

In my adapter I inflate checkbox layout with the following code:

```
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.listview_item_checkbox, null);

            CheckedTextView checkbox = ((CheckedTextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.text1))
```

listview_item_checkbox.xml

```
    <CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
     />
```

Comment: I would guess that it is somethinh in your layout (R.layout.listview_item_text). Can you post it?

Comment: It is because you are creating your own adapter "WifiListAdapter" and not using the standard ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Can you post your text1.xml? And you don't need this code - if (checkBox != null) checkBox.toggle();

Comment: Check the answer of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074888/listview-setchoicemode-not-showing-up)

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah I didn't really undestand. Does it mean that there is now way calling this method on custom Adapter?

Comment: As stated in the answer: "Calling setChoiceMode is not enough to display checkboxes beside your list rows.". So, you must update R.layout.listview_item_text.xml to include a checkbox or use the Android default as in Tobias answer.

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah updated the question. And right now I am calling `WifiListAdapter<WifiListItem> adapter = new WifiListAdapter<WifiListItem>(
    this, R.layout.listview_item_checkbox, listItems);` and still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of your code:

```
if (checkBox != null)
        checkBox.toggle();
```

Try something like this:

```
if (checkBox != null) checkBox.setChecked(l.getCheckedItemPositions().get(position));
```

If you can - improve yur code (create `CheckableFrameLayout` as parent layout of your List Item). `ListView` keep [BooleanSparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) of checked positions (you can get it with method [getCheckedItemPositions()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPositions%28%29)). In code ([grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/AbsListView.java#AbsListView.updateOnScreenCheckedViews%28%29)) it set `View` checked or not by itself only if `View` is implementing [Checkable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html). If create `CheckableFrameLayout` and sat as main parent, you do not have to handle these cases in the adapter.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't really get it. `CheckedTextView` is implementing `Checkable`. I understood that `AbsListView` keeps tracking states of checkboxes in `mCheckStates` member variable. the problem is why it is not handling it properly if that item in the list is implementing `Checkable`?

Comment: Sorry, I may have just misunderstood. What if you just remove this part of your code: `if (checkBox != null) checkBox.toggle();`, because when you use method `toggle()` in `onListItemClick()`, you are uncheck just checked item.

Comment: Thanks. I got it finally. I had LinearLayout as a parent view for my checkbox. So, it was not implementing Checkable. p.s. My code right now is as following: `protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  final int finalPosition = position;
  if (v instanceof CheckedTextView) {
   CheckedTextView checkBox = (CheckedTextView) v;`

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you have to use a widget that implements [Checkable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html). Try with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`. If you need two lines then implement something similar.

Comment: You can not inflate your text view and cast it to a `CheckedTextView`. I guess that `WifiListAdpapter` is your own class. I don't know what you do with the arguments, but as far as I can tell your `getView()` method must return objects that implements `Checkable` for multiple choice to work. Otherwise you have to manage the checked state yourself.

Comment: I have different views ( item lists ) in my `ListView`. So, I am doing checking ( != null ), so if the checkbox was clicked. Are you saying that ALL objects returned by `getView()` method must implement Checkable so multiple choice will work?

Comment: Okay.So I am doing this. I am not casting Text view to CheckedTextView. I have checkboxes in my list. Added checkbox xml in the question.

Comment: It is not enough that you have a checkable item in the layout. The top level widget in your layout must be checkable. Look at this: http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java#1891

Comment: But I have my top widget as checkable. Where exactly should I look in the android ListView source code? I even tried to delete all items except Checkable ones and still no result

Comment: Okay. From source code I found:
`if (child instanceof Checkable) {
1892                ((Checkable) child).setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position));` `mCheckStates.get(position))` because I manage the states of checkboxes by myself in my custom adapter, does it mean that it won't work?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You need to clean this up. For example, is R.layout.listview_item_text.xml still used?

Comment: Well, it is used generally, but for testing purposes I am not adding items this type right now to my ListView.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that there is some problem in the source code (event for lastest version at the time I am writing this answer, 4.3r2.1). Here is the problem:

```
1899        if (mChoiceMode != CHOICE_MODE_NONE && mCheckStates != null) {
1900            if (child instanceof Checkable) {
1901                ((Checkable) child).setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position));
1902            } else if (getContext().getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion
1903                    >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
1904                child.setActivated(mCheckStates.get(position));
1905            }
1906        }
```

Source code:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/widget/ListView.java?av=f

The easiest answer to your question, if your minSDK is 11, is customize the checkbox like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_selected"/>
 <item android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_deselected" />
 <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_deselected" />
 <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_selected" />
</selector>
```

Save it to the drawable folder as xml file and refer it as layout.

The middle level solution is set onItemClickListener and perform different behavior depending on the choice mode.

Here is the source code which works:
https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/CustomizedListRow

And the hard but correct solution is the one from MarvinLab, which you can find it here:
http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/29/custom-listview-ability-check-items/

Related issue:
[What is the difference between the states selected, checked and activated in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504860/what-is-the-difference-between-the-states-selected-checked-and-activated-in-and)